# If $A\subset B$ then $\overline{A}\subset B$ or $\overline{B}\subset A$.

Tags: general-topology

If $A\subset B$ in a topological space does it imply that $\overline{A}\subset B$ or $\overline{B}\subset A$? What about for the real line $\mathbb{R}$?

More importantly, what is this condition imply or equivalent to?

I come up with this question when I am trying to describe when the inclusion chains $A_1\subset A_2\subset...$ and $\overline{A}_1\subset \overline{A}_2\subset...$ composite to give another inclusion chain.

**I will reformulate this question in a more proper context. I will try to see if it works in all subrings of $\mathbb{R}$-see the mo thread in the comment.**

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Gibbs I am aware this might have tons of conterexamples, but I come up with this question from my mo thread, and here is the link: https://mathoverflow.net/q/342384/132430

Comment: Does not matter, people are giving plenty of examples below.

Comment: So the question I’m most concern with is what can this property be equivalent to in topological spaces. But I’m not a topologist so I haven’t got any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and take $A= (0,1)$ and $B= (0,1]$.

Generally, you know if $A \subset B$ then $\overline{A} \subset \overline{B}$. To look for your own counterexamples, you just need a set with a limit point which will not be in the original set which contained it. Can you come up with 'fancier' examples?

EDIT. Since Jose beat me to the example I was going to use by a few seconds, note this even fails in the case where $A=B$ and $A$ is any non-closed set, because if $A$ is not closed, then certainly $A \subset \overline{A}$ and not the other way around. [This works assuming you take $\subset$ to mean either contained in or strictly contained in and not only strictly contained in. The notation is not everywhere used consistently.]

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb R$, if $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(0,1]$, then $A\subset B$, but$$\overline A\not\subset B\text{ and }\overline B\not\subset A.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \{\frac1n\,|\,n\geqslant 1\}$ and $B = A \cup \{2\}$.